# What is the All time Top Query in Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow

What is the all time top Question in Stack Overflow in terms of maximum votes? I am interested to know the top questions (say top 100) by maximum votes, answers, and views. Besides learning from them, I want to study the correlation between these questions. How can I get them ? I am aware that Stack Overflow gives Top Questions by interesting, featured, hot, week, and month but not by maximum votes, answers, and views. Any  suggestions ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions?sort=votes

Comment: And to find top voted answers http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=is%3aanswer

Answer (score 0):

Currently, it is [Why is it faster to process a sorted array than an unsorted array?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11227809/866022). In the future, to find out what the top voted question is, just sort the question list by votes (www.stackoverflow.com/questions?sort=votes).

Answer (score 0):

You can compose all kind of queries on your own by using the [Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/). It gets updated on a weekly basis.

Answer (score 0):

It kind of depends!The [link you have been provided](http://www.stackoverflow.com/questions?sort=votes) will show you the most upvoted question in tags that you do not have ignored. For me, because I have a bunch of tags including [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) it's [The definitive guide to form-based website authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/549/the-definitive-guide-to-forms-based-website-authentication) but your milage may vary.