# OP's username is showing as a deleted user

Tags: bug, status-bydesign

A [question was asked](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/160886/what-is-the-all-time-top-query-in-stack-overflow), and I noticed a user's mini-profile-thingy is showing as if they were a past/deleted user. It looks odd and thought this may be unintentional. Maybe someone can shed light onto why this looks the way it does?

[image: Screenshot!]

Comment: @Shan sorry to put you in the spotlight :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The question was migrated from Stack Overflow. The user doesn't have a profile here yet (unlike most metas, MSO has a separate account/rep system), however he will have been notified by the migration and ought to create a profile for himself soon :)

[image]

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1020149/shan) is the user's profile on SO.

Btw, a deleted user will show up as `userXYZ` over there -- the username is reverted to the default during deletion.

Comment: I seeeee.... thought it was odd and noticed the *migrated from...*. cool thanks!